# django-haystack rebuild_index command fails

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying install Elasticsearch for my project via django-haystack. I'm using this [tutorial](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/tutorial.html), but when I run a command

> ./manage.py rebuild_index

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 26, in handle
    call_command('update_index', **options)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 119, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 195, in handle
    return super(Command, self).handle(*items, **options)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 548, in handle
    label_output = self.handle_label(label, **options)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 200, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 243, in update_backend
    commit=self.commit, max_retries=self.max_retries)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 107, in do_update
    LOG.error(error_msg, exc_info=True, **error_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1174, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retries'
```

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    full_address = models.TextField(null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name='company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**search_indexes.py**

```
class CompanyIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    short_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='short_description')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
    email = indexes.CharField(model_attr='email')
    full_address = indexes.CharField(model_attr='full_address')

    def get_model(self):
        return Company
```

Environment:

- Django==1.9.2
- django-haystack==2.5.dev0
- elasticsearch==2.3.0
- elasticsearch-dsl==2.0.0
- logging==0.4.9.6
- pyelasticsearch==1.4
- urllib3==1.14

Comment: Could you try pip install django-haystack==2.4.1 and re-check

Comment: I need django-haystack==2.5.dev0 because I'm using django 1.9. See this [github issue](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1282)

Comment: When I try use haystack 2.4.1, `rebuild_index` command works, but I gets problem `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_model'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is specific error for `haystack==2.5.dev0`.
The reason is what you didn't create(or it has a wrong name) the template `search/indexes/myapp/modelname_text.txt`